# MySQL select count(*) statement excluding minimium value

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions, mysql-error-1111

I have a simple MySQL select statement:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT FROM MY_TABLE WHERE TIME_STAMP > ?
```

But I do not want to count the first/earliest row if the TIME_STAMP for that earliest row is greater than my WHERE threshold. Something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT FROM MY_TABLE WHERE TIME_STAMP > ? AND TIME_STAMP > $earliest
```

Obviously I can get the earliest TIME_STAMP with an additional prior query. But I was wandering if I can do it all in one. I tried this but throws an "Invalid use of group function" error:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT FROM MY_TABLE WHERE TIME_STAMP > ? AND TIME_STAMP > MIN(TIME_STAMP)
```

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Could you clarify with an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last query would work if you got the `MIN` value from a nested select. Group functions need context, of what do you want the minimum?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT FROM MY_TABLE WHERE TIME_STAMP > ? AND TIME_STAMP > (SELECT   MIN(TIME_STAMP) FROM MY_TABLE)
```